# Google Plus Integration is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-play-services

I follow tutorial of AndroidHive and still I didn't get any response from an app. I follow all latest instruction like `google-service.json` etc. Here is my code.

I am not getting any error in the application while clicking on *sign in with Google* button, it's asking me to select Google account but after selecting account there is no response. I provide my log cat also.

**Logcat**

```
    02-10 12:53:11.108 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    02-10 12:53:11.175 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/asset: Success to oxygen resources /system/framework/oxygen-framework-res.apk
    02-10 12:53:11.248 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
    02-10 12:53:11.248 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
    02-10 12:53:11.408 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/asset: Success to oxygen resources /system/framework/oxygen-framework-res.apk
    02-10 12:53:11.409 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
    02-10 12:53:11.409 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
    02-10 12:53:11.531 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    02-10 12:53:11.553 22166-22220/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    02-10 12:53:11.562 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map...
    02-10 12:53:11.597 22166-22220/com.example.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1.C4__release_AU ()
                                                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                           Build Date: 08/11/15 Tue
                                                                           Local Branch: mybranch12886200
                                                                           Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1.c4
                                                                           Local Patches: NONE
                                                                           Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
    02-10 12:53:11.599 22166-22220/com.example.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    02-10 12:53:11.626 22166-22220/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    02-10 12:53:11.663 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/ThreadedRenderer: mThreadGroupCpuId 2 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
    02-10 12:53:11.836 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    02-10 12:53:11.836 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@56b613a time:542295804
    02-10 12:53:13.632 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/ThreadedRenderer: mThreadGroupCpuId 2 mRenderThreadCpuId 2 affinity
    02-10 12:53:13.748 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
    02-10 12:53:14.002 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    02-10 12:53:17.013 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    02-10 12:53:17.046 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@56b613a time:542301014
    02-10 12:53:17.059 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    02-10 12:53:22.909 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
    02-10 12:53:22.948 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    02-10 12:53:25.334 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    02-10 12:53:25.379 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@56b613a time:542309347
    02-10 12:53:25.394 22166-22166/com.example.myapplication D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    02-10 12:53:27.221 22166-22205/com.example.myapplication I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
```

**Project level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

**App level build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**MainActity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
// Logcat tag
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

// Profile pic image size in pixels
private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
 * from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

    // Button click listeners
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Initializing google plus api client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Button on click listener
 * */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            // Signin button clicked
            signInWithGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            // Signout button clicked
            signOutFromGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            // Revoke access button clicked
            revokeGplusAccess();
            break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();

    // Update the UI after signin
    updateUI(true);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    updateUI(false);
}

/**
 * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
 * */
private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/**
 * Revoking access from google
 * */
private void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }

                });
    }
}
/**
 * Sign-out from google
 * */
private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
/**
 * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
 * */
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProfile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_logout_from_google"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_revoke_access"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_revoke_access"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Is it possible for this `if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) ` to be false? It isn't handled in the code ...

Comment: I checked in logcat with debug . no error in that . @Fildor